# Existence of non-coprime between an integer and an arithmetic sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

Take two relatively prime numbers $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. $gcd(m,n) = 1$) where $m \neq 1$.

Show that:

$$\forall a \in \mathbb{Z} \textrm{ s.t. } 0<a<n$$

$$\exists i \in \mathbb{Z^+} \textrm{ s.t. }\gcd( n-a + i*a , m)\neq 1$$

**Attempt:**

I can think of a way of simplifiying the problem.

Say we want to make $n-a + i*a$ a multiple of $m$ (lets say $k*m$)

Then
$$n-a + i*a = k*m$$
$$i = \frac{k*m-n+a}{a}$$
$$i = \frac{k*m-n}{a}+1$$

So that now the problem is whether

$$\forall m \forall n \forall a \exists k$$

such that 
$$ k*m-n\equiv 0\pmod a $$

Is this simplification going to work?
What is the proof?
is there a counterexample for it?

Comment: you stated in the begining $(s,t)$ but you did not use them?

Comment: This doesn't hold if $a=0$ and $\gcd(n,m) = 1$.

Comment: fixed those problems

Comment: This won't hold if $a$ divides $m$.